# Inserting/Updating Master-Details on Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api

I 've been digging around about Master-Detail relotionship and how to implement it with Entity Framework (4.1). I have two classes:

```
[Table("master")]
public class Master
{
    [Key]
    [Column("id")]
    public int id {get; set;}
    public virtual ICollection<Detail> Children { get; set;}
}

[Table("detail")]
public class AuthGrantDetailEntity
{
    [Key]
    [Column("id")]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("MasterId")]
    public virtual Master MasterEntity { get; set; }
}
```

So, up to here everything looking good. I have been reading a lot of comments about this situations, but I didn´t found an answer to it (or maybe I didn´t understand it).
If i want to insert both Master and Detail, I did understand and i get it to work just fine. For eg:

```
using (var repo = MasterRepository)
{
    Master masterEntity = new Master();
    master.id = 1;
    Detail detailEntity = new Detail();
    detailEntity.id = 1;
    masterEntity.Children = new List<Detail>;
    masterEntity.Childern.add(detailEntity);
    repo.Add(masterEntity);
 }
```

My question is the following:
   Suppose that after inserting the Master and Detail and save those changes, I have to add some new details that belong to the Master inserted before. For doing that I have to check if the Master exists and if exists add the new detail (all this is by coding. i´m doing right now this way). Is there a way that EF checks if the Master exists and then insert the new details in into it using the code written above? With this I mean re-use the code written above (or some other code that works for my case) in order to function whether the Master exists or not, and not to have a duplicated primary key exception.

The reason of doing this, is that I want to remove some logic from the code and avoid multiple Data Base access. For what I see on my searching I think there it can be done, unless I do a manual check if the Master exists, but I still have some hope that any of you faced the same issue, and found a workaround to this.

Regards, Matias.